# Gulp task with prerequisite does not start

Tags: gulp

I have a task which depends on a previous task which merges multiple streams and return the resulting stream. The task which depends on it never seems to run.

This is my dependency:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var concat = require('gulp-concat');
var sourcemaps = require('gulp-sourcemaps');
var less = require('gulp-less');
var minifyCss = require('gulp-minify-css');
var merge = require('gulp-merge');
var cached = require('gulp-cached');

gulp.task('css:minify', function () {
    var bootstrapLess = gulp.src(['plugins/bootstrap/less/bootstrap.less'])
        .pipe(cached('bootstrap less'))
        .pipe(less())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('plugins/bootstrap/less/'));

    var aceLess = gulp.src(['plugins/ace-admin/less/ace.less'])
        .pipe(cached('ace less'))
        .pipe(less())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('plugins/ace-admin/less/'));

    var ace = gulp.src(files.css.ace)
        .pipe(cached('ace min'))
        .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
        .pipe(minifyCss())
        .pipe(concat('aes.ace.min.css'))
        .pipe(sourcemaps.write('./'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('Content/'));

    var css = gulp.src(files.css.all)
        .pipe(cached('aes.min'))
        .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
        .pipe(minifyCss())
        .pipe(concat('aes.all.min.css'))
        .pipe(sourcemaps.write('./'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('Content/'));

    console.log('css minification in progress');

    return merge(bootstrapLess, aceLess, ace, css);
});
```

The task which uses them is as follows:

```
gulp.task('test', ['css:minify'], function () {
    console.log('testing');
});
```

I get the following output:

```
[14:32:53] Starting 'css:minify'...
css minification in progress
Process terminated with code 0.
```

The `css:minify` task never reports that it has finished, and the `test` task never logs anything to the console. My expectation was that the dependency would return a stream, and that the `test` task would run when the stream finished. What have I done wrong which prevents this from happening?

**Edit:** it seems that the problem is the `concat` within the `ace` and `css` sections of the `css:minify` task (because if I comment out those lines everything works fine), but I still can't see why it prevents the task from working.

Comment: There's no way to answer this when half your code is just `doStuff` and `doMoreStuff`.

Comment: Ah interesting, I thought I must have misunderstood something in how I'd set up my test task. I'll fill in the detail for the examples, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the problem was something to do with `gulp-merge`. When I changed it to instead use `merge-stream` everything worked as expected.